# Does launchMode in manifest have any effect for service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-manifest

```
<service
            android:name="MyService"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

Does android:launchMode in manifest have any effect for service or is only for Activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does launchMode in manifest have any effect for service?

**No,** `Service` listen to the intent filter. Then having this `Service` open your `Activity` where `launchMode` of activity will decide how to launch the `Activity` on the screen.

---

**Launchmode** is concerned about the way **`Activity`** is launched on the screen. And we can set it as property in activity tag

[Detail about the Launch mode of Activity](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

Where as , **Service** itself is a tag  that lack a visual user interface. They're used to implement long-running background operations or a rich communications API that can be called by other applications.

[Developer guide for Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html)